# Trigger dataLayer.push when user successfully registered or logged

Tags: forms, triggers, prestashop, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'am having an issue with the **deployement of GTM** on a **prestashop** *(1.7)* shop.
I must **send** a dataLayer.push when an **user login**(true or false) and one when an user
**registers**.

The **problem** is that I don't know **where to trigger** the dataLayer.push only if the user successfully completed the form with the good informations..

Hopefuly you guys can help me out since I'am pertty new to Prestashop

Answer (score 0):

you should use Prestashop [hooks](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/)

and build a simple module that execute your code when the hooks are fired.

You can use the following hooks to suit you needs :

**actionCustomerAccountAdd** and
**actionAuthentication**

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your advice, seems like hooks is the way to go. I did not find a lot of docs on how to setup a JS script triggered by a fired hook, do you have any tips on this ? :/

Comment: "Quick and dirty" way is to just echo your JS code inside the hook. Use the Module Generator provided by Prestashop as a template for a quick start.